# Visually Display progress of algorithm

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to visually show some algorithms in Processing (but really, this question applies to any language with a GUI framework). My question is, a program with a draw loop that updates based on frames per second, how do you execute an algorithm and update a visual display of it?

An example is if I display an array of random values as a bar graph. I want to sort this array using different sorts (bubble sort, quicksort, merge sort). How do I display each step of the algorithm by showing each swap in a new animation frame?

Or another example is path finding. I want to show the steps of BFS, DFS, A*, and not only the final solution path (all the pats searched).

Examples of the visual affect I'm looking for can be found on Wikipedia articles on these algorithms:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Astar_progress_animation.gif

The issue is by the time the algorithm finishes, the draw loop has only looped once, so the user doesn't see the progress.

The only thing I can think of is to have a "State" object which contains the relevant values for each step of the algorithm. When it finishes, loop through each state and visually show it. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is an open ended question, but basically, you would need to take advantage of a good animation framework ([TimingFramework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework), [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)) or 2D gaming engine

Comment: You don't understand my question. My issue is that in the draw loop only one iteration will occur when the algorithm finishes, so it will start off unsorted then finish sorted. I want to animate the algorithm's progresss

Comment: You need to construct you algorithm's so that they can perform over a period of time (seeding the current progress to them), that way through each cycle, you can increment the progression and update the algorithm and screen.  This would be a value of time past against time to run

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * A panel that can show a demonstration of Quicksort in action. The items to be
 * sorted are the hues of a set of vertical bars. When sorted, the bars form a
 * spectrum from red to violet. Initially, the bars are sorted. There is a Start
 * button. When the user clicks this button, the order of the bars is randomized
 * and then Quicksort is applied. During the sort, a black bar marks the
 * location of an empty space from which the "pivot" element has been removed.
 * The user can abort the sort by clicking the button again.
 * <p>
 * The main point of this program is to demonstrate threads, with very simple
 * inter-thread communication. The recursive Quicksort algorithm is run in a
 * separate thread. The abort operation is implemented by setting the value of a
 * volatile variable that is checked periodically by the thread. When the user
 * aborts the sort before it finishes, the value of the variable changes; the
 * thread sees the change and exits.
 * <p>
 * This class contains a main() routine that allows the demo to be run as a
 * stand-alone application.
 */
public class QuicksortThreadDemo extends JPanel {

    /**
     * This main routine just shows a panel of type QuicksortThreadDemo.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Demo: Recursion in a Thread");
        QuicksortThreadDemo content = new QuicksortThreadDemo();
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.pack();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        window.setLocation((screenSize.width - window.getWidth()) / 2,
                (screenSize.height - window.getHeight()) / 2);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private final static int ARRAY_SIZE = 150; // The number of colored bars.

    private int[] hue = new int[ARRAY_SIZE]; // The array that will be sorted.
    private Color[] palette = new Color[ARRAY_SIZE]; // Colors in spectral
                                                        // order.
    private Display display; // The panel that displays the colored bars.
    private JButton startButton; // The button that starts and stops the demo.

    private Runner runner; // The thread that runs the recursion.

    private volatile boolean running; // Set to true while recursion is running;
                                        // This is set to true as a signal to
                                        // the
                                        // thread to abort.

    /**
     * When the user aborts the recursion before it finishes, an exception of
     * this type is thrown to end the recursion cleanly.
     */
    private class ThreadTerminationException extends RuntimeException {
    }

    /**
     * A subpanel of type Display shows the colored bars that are being sorted.
     * The current pivot, if any, is shown in black. A 3-pixel gray border is
     * left around the bars.
     */
    private class Display extends JPanel {
        Display() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(606, 206));
            setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            double barWidth = (double) (getWidth() - 6) / hue.length;
            int h = getHeight() - 6;
            for (int i = 0; i < hue.length; i++) {
                int x1 = 3 + (int) (i * barWidth + 0.49);
                int x2 = 3 + (int) ((i + 1) * barWidth + 0.49);
                int w = x2 - x1;
                if (hue[i] == -1)
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                else
                    g.setColor(palette[hue[i]]);
                g.fillRect(x1, 3, w, h);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The constructor sets up the panel, containing the Display and the Start
     * button below it.
     */
    public QuicksortThreadDemo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            palette[i] = Color.getHSBColor((i * 230) / (ARRAY_SIZE * 255.0F),
                    1, 1);
            hue[i] = i;
        }
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        display = new Display();
        add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.add(startButton);
        bottom.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (running)
                    stop();
                else
                    start();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the user clicks the Start button, while no
     * thread is running. It starts a new thread and sets the signaling
     * variable, running, to true; Also changes the text on the Start button to
     * "Finish".
     */
    private void start() {
        startButton.setText("Finish");
        runner = new Runner();
        running = true; // Set the signal before starting the thread!
        runner.start();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the user clicks the button while a thread is
     * running. A signal is sent to the thread to terminate, by setting the
     * value of the signaling variable, running, to false.
     */
    private void stop() {

        /*
         * Set the value of the signaling variable to false as a signal to the
         * thread to terminate.
         */

        running = false;

        /*
         * Wake the thread, in case it is sleeping, to get a more immediate
         * reaction to the signal.
         */

        runner.interrupt();

        /*
         * Wait for the thread to stop before setting runner = null. One second
         * should be plenty of time for this to happen, but in case something
         * goes wrong, it's better not to
         */

        try {
            runner.join(1000); // Wait for thread to stop. One second should be
                                // plenty of time.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        runner = null;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called frequently by the thread that is running the
     * recursion, in order to insert delays. It calls the repaint() method of
     * the display to allow the user to see what is going on; the delay will
     * give the system a chance to actually update the display. Since this
     * method is called regularly while the recursion is in progress, it is also
     * used as a convenient place to check the value of the signaling variable,
     * running. If the value of running has been set to false, this method
     * throws an exception of type ThreadTerminatedException. This exception
     * will cause all active levels of the recursion to be terminated. It is
     * caught in the run() method of the thread.
     * 
     * @param millis
     *            The number of milliseconds to sleep.
     */
    private void delay(int millis) {
        if (!running)
            throw new ThreadTerminationException();
        display.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        if (!running)
            throw new ThreadTerminationException();
    }

    /**
     * The basic non-recursive QuickSortStep algorithm, which uses hue[lo] as a
     * "pivot" and rearranges elements of the hue array from positions lo
     * through hi so that positions the pivot value is in its correct location,
     * with smaller items to the left and bigger items to the right. The
     * position of the pivot is returned. In this version, we conceptually
     * remove the pivot from the array, leaving an empty space. The space is
     * marked by a -1, and it moves around as the algorithm proceeds. It is
     * shown as a black bar in the display. Every time a change is made, the
     * delay() method is called to insert a 1/10 second delay to let the user
     * see the change.
     */
    private int quickSortStep(int lo, int hi) {
        int pivot = hue[lo]; // Save pivot item.
        hue[lo] = -1; // Mark location lo as empty.
        delay(100);
        while (true) {
            while (hi > lo && hue[hi] > pivot)
                hi--;
            if (hi == lo)
                break;
            hue[lo] = hue[hi]; // Move hue[hi] into empty space.
            hue[hi] = -1; // Mark location hi as empty.
            delay(100);
            while (lo < hi && hue[lo] < pivot)
                lo++;
            if (hi == lo)
                break;
            hue[hi] = hue[lo]; // Move hue[lo] into empty space.
            hue[lo] = -1; // Mark location lo as empty.
            delay(100);
        }
        hue[lo] = pivot; // Move pivot item into the empty space.
        delay(100);
        return lo;
    }

    /**
     * The recursive quickSort algorithm, for sorting the hue array from
     * positions lo through hi into increasing order. Most of the actual work is
     * done in quickSortStep().
     */
    private void quickSort(int lo, int hi) {
        if (hi <= lo)
            return;
        int mid = quickSortStep(lo, hi);
        quickSort(lo, mid - 1);
        quickSort(mid + 1, hi);
    }

    /**
     * This class defines the treads that run the recursive QuickSort algorithm.
     * The thread begins by randomizing the array. It then calls quickSort() to
     * sort the entire array. If quickSort() is aborted by a
     * ThreadTerminationExcpetion, which would be caused by the user clicking
     * the Finish button, then the thread will restore the array to sorted order
     * before terminating, so that whether or not the quickSort is aborted, the
     * array ends up sorted.
     */
    private class Runner extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = hue.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { // Randomize array.
                    int r = (int) ((i + 1) * Math.random());
                    int temp = hue[r];
                    hue[r] = hue[i];
                    hue[i] = temp;
                }
                delay(1000); // Wait one second before starting the sort.
                quickSort(0, hue.length - 1); // Sort the whole array.
            } catch (ThreadTerminationException e) { // User aborted quickSort.
                for (int i = 0; i < hue.length; i++)
                    hue[i] = i;
            } finally {// Make sure running is false and button label is
                        // correct.
                running = false;
                startButton.setText("Start");
                display.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

} // end QuicksortThreadDemo
```

`

Comment: Gives you the visualation of quicksort, by sorting colors. May as well be used wit other sorts. I saw this in Java Notes 6.0 website.

Answer (score 1):

I think a way to do it (but may not be the best way) is to write code for separate steps and then use sikuli or some other GUI scripts to have the automated output.

Or simply write the code in MATLAB script, then use the + and - button to see the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches you can take:

Rewrite your algorythm so that it can be incremented with a varible. Then increment each iteration of the "loop" in draw. Here is an example of someone trying this approach in processing.

http://www.processing.org/discourse/alpha/board_Programs_action_display_num_1059766998.html

Write to an offscreen buffer and save each frame / iteration of the loop, then display them later. I have left the bubble sort algorithm from the example above and the methods to draw per frame so you can see how I have modified the structure to use a buffer.

```
int[] myArray;
PGraphics pg;
ArrayList<PImage> frameBufferList;

void setup() {
 size(400, 400);
 frameRate(15);
 frameBufferList = new ArrayList<PImage>();
 myArray = randomArray(20);
 bubbleSortSaveFrame(myArray);
}

void draw() {
  background(127);
  image(frameBufferList.get(frameCount % frameBufferList.size()), 0, 0);
}

int[] randomArray(int numOfElements) {
  int[] returnArray = new int[numOfElements];
  for (int i = 0; i < returnArray.length; i++) {
    returnArray[i] = floor(random(0, height));
  }
  return returnArray;
}

void displayArray(int[] arrToDisplay) {
  float step = float(width) / float(arrToDisplay.length);
  for (int i = 0; i < arrToDisplay.length; i++) {
    rectMode(CORNERS);
    rect(i*step, height, (i+1)*step, height-arrToDisplay[i]);
  }
}

void displayArrayBuffer(int[] arrToDisplay) {
  pg = createGraphics(width, height, P2D); // setup buffer
  pg.beginDraw(); // start buffer
  pg.background(127);  
  float step = float(width) / float(arrToDisplay.length);
  for (int i = 0; i < arrToDisplay.length; i++) {
    pg.rectMode(CORNERS);
    pg.rect(i*step, height, (i+1)*step, height-arrToDisplay[i]);
  }
  pg.endDraw(); // end buffer
  frameBufferList.add(pg);
}

void bubbleSort(int array[]) 
{ 
  int i, j; 
  boolean sorted = false;  
  // while the array isn't sorted 
  while (!sorted) { 
    sorted = true; 
    // loop through array 
    for (i=0;i<array.length-1;i++) { 
     if (array[i] > array[i+1]) { 
       // swap values 
       j = array[i]; 
       array[i] = array[i+1]; 
       array[i+1] = j; 
       //println(array); 
       // trigger's been hit, array isn't sorted. 
       sorted = false; 
     } 
    } 
  } 
} 

void bubbleSortSaveFrame(int array[]) 
{ 
  int i, j; 
  boolean sorted = false; 
  // while the array isn't sorted 
  while (!sorted) { 
    sorted = true; 
    // loop through array 
    for (i=0;i<array.length-1;i++) { 
             displayArrayBuffer(array); // save the frame
     if (array[i] > array[i+1]) { 
       // swap values 
       j = array[i]; 
       array[i] = array[i+1]; 
       array[i+1] = j; 
       //println(array); 
       // trigger's been hit, array isn't sorted. 
       sorted = false; 
     } 
    } 
  }
}
```

Note: normally you use one buffer per frame, in this case we are creating a buffer for each image being saved so you can run out of memory if you are creating thousands of images. Dose anyone have another solution to using PGraphics / buffer without the memory hit?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer for your question (gr8 question btw). It depends on the algorithm. Let's take bubble sort as an example. This algorithm has a finite number of steps until it finishes (i.e. you can make an assumption of it's worst case performance).

**Stolen from wikipedia:**

```
  procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
     repeat     
       swapped = false
       for i = 1 to length(A) - 1 inclusive do:
         /* if this pair is out of order */
         if A[i-1] > A[i] then
           /* swap them and remember something changed */
           swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
           swapped = true
         end if
       end for
     until not swapped
 end procedure
```

You know that you will have (in the worst case) n loops for the **repeat** loop and n loops for the **for** loop (n square complexity). The loops in the for are fast and you don't have to update your status bar for each loop (the user will not see the progress, and even the GUI is not fast enough to update all the statuses in the for). So your progress step would be n/100. At the end of each while loop, update the status bar by that progress, and after the **repeat** finishes, update to 100%.

You will have to analyze each algorithm and find a solution like this for each one. As I said, there is no general magic solution.